# clang source-based coverage: show files with no coverage

Tags: c++, code-coverage, clang++

I'm building a lib with clang's code-based coverage instrumentation, i.e. with `-fprofile-instr-generate` and `-fcoverage-mapping`, flags. Now I'm setting up tests and coverage reporting.

For example, assume I have libfoo that contains

```
file1.cpp
file2.cpp
file3.cpp
```

This compiles with the above flags and now I write a test application, `testFoo`, that links against `libFoo` and exercises code from `file1.cpp` and `file2.cpp` but nothing from `file3.cpp`. When I run `testFoo` and the print the code coverage, `llvm-cov report ...`, I only see reports for `file1.cpp` and `file2.cpp`.

How do I get the report to show that `file3.cpp` has zero coverage?

Comment: Is libFoo a static library? If so you may need to use `-Wl,--whole-archive` when you link your program against it. Otherwise you're only pulling in file1.o and file2.o

Comment: thanks, that did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is libFoo a static library? If so you need to place `-Wl,--whole-archive` and `-Wl,--no-whole-archive` around libFoo.a when you link your program against it.

Otherwise you're only putting file1.o and file2.o into the final outputted binary, and the coverage tool will be unaware of file3.o.